# Google Sheets Set value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Trying to write a script that prompts with a popup box to enter a value then adds that value to the already entered amount.

```
function addDKP(){
  // Prompt for the value
  var amount =  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Please Enter the DKP Amount").getResponseText();

  var sheetName = "Sheet1" ;
  var selection = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSelection();

  // Returns the current highlighted cell in the one of the active ranges.
  var currentCell = selection.getCurrentCell();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var range = selection.getActiveRange();
  var value = range.getValue();

  range.setValue(amount + value );
}
```

That script is working but just adds the amount entered to the end of the already entered value.

Example:

```
Current Cell value = 45
Run script and enter 2 as a value
End of script cell value = 452
```

Expected cell value should be `47`

Any suggestions as to why this is happening would be appreciated.

Comment: Are these actually numbers? You may use `range.setValue(Number(amount) + Number(value));`

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Legend